# passing random values from one array to another without repetitions

Tags: actionscript-3

I have an array (say 'origA') which contains 20 values and also another array (say "itemA" with only 1 value in it. I need to push **any 10 random values** of "origA" into "itemA". But i cannot push a same value which is already pushed into "itemA".

How can we do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a copy of `origA` and remove from it the items you add to `itemA`:

Non optimized version:

```
var origA:Array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
var itemA:Array = [0];

var copyA:Array = origA.concat();
var N:int = 10;
var n:int = Math.min(N, copyA.length);

for (var i:int = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // Get random value
    var index:int = Math.floor(Math.random() * copyA.length);
    var value:int = copyA[index];
    // Remove the selected value from copyA
    copyA.splice(index, 1);
    // Add the selected value to itemA
    itemA.push(value);
}

trace(itemA);
//0,1,7,2,6,4,3,5
```

Optimized version (no calls to `length`, `indexOf`, `splice` or `push` inside the loop):

```
var origA:Array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
var itemA:Array = [0];

var copyA:Array = origA.concat();
var copyALength:int = copyA.length;
var itemALength:int = itemA.length;
var N:int = 10;
var n:int = Math.min(N, copyALength);
for (var i:int = 0; i < n; i++) {
    // Get random value
    var index:int = Math.floor(Math.random() * copyALength);
    var value:int = copyA[index];
    // Remove the selected value from copyA
    copyA[index] = copyA[--copyALength];
    // Add the selected value to itemA
    itemA[itemALength++] = value;
}

trace(itemA);
//0,2,5,7,4,1,3,6
```

---

**Edit1:** If your original array has only a few items, use my first version or any other solution in the other answers. But if it may have thousands items or more, then I recommend you use my optimized version.

---

**Edit:2** Here is the time taken to copy `1,000` randomly chosen items from an array containing `1,000,000` items:

- All other versions: `2000ms`
- Optimized version: `12ms`
- Optimized version without cloning the original array: `1ms`

Comment: Nice, though I figure working with an array of length 10 or even under 100 doesn't *really* need a solution that works without `indexOf()`, though I admit it's good for people looking for a similar solution with much larger arrays :)

Comment: I used a copy of the original array mainly to avoid altering it (using `splice()`) and not to avoid the use of `indexOf()`. It's only in the second optimized version that I avoid calling costly methods: `length`, `indexOf`, `splice` and `push`.

Comment: I have to agree on the `indexOf()` part - it will iterate from index 0 until it finds the item, which can be quite costly with a larger array.

Comment: @sch I can confirm your benchmarks.  That's pretty impressive. I can also say that it's the call to `splice()` that made my solution slow. I will from now on adopt your way of removing values - thank you for the inspiration!

Answer (score 2):

```
// Define how many random numbers are required.
const REQUIRED:int = 10;

// Loop until either the original array runs out of numbers,
// or the destination array reaches the required length.
while(origA.length > 0 && itemA.length < REQUIRED)
{
    // Decide on a random index and pull the value from there.
    var i:int = Math.random() * origA.length;
    var r:Number = origA[i];

    // Add the value to the destination array if it does not exist yet.
    if(itemA.indexOf(r) == -1)
    {
        itemA.push(r);
    }

    // Remove the value we looked at this iteration.
    origA.splice(i, 1);
}
```

Comment: I am sorry if i wasn't clear but I need any 10 random values without repetitions, not all.

Comment: @Marty Wallace all the values are different in the "origA" this problem should not occur. anyways, when i said without repetitions I meant if one random value is pushed into "itemA" from "origA" the same value should not be pushed again. You understand what i mean?

Comment: @weltraumpirat `Math.random()` never hands out `1` so assigning to int like I have always returns a value up to the length - 1...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a real short one. Remove random items from the original array until you reach MAX, then concat to the target Array:

```
const MAX:int = 10;
var orig:Array = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
var target:Array = [];
var tmp:Array = [];
var i : int = -1;
var len : int = orig.length;
while (++i < MAX && len > 0) {
    var index:int = int( Math.random()*len );
    tmp[i] = orig[index];
    orig[index] = orig[--len];
}
target = target.concat(tmp);
```

**EDIT**

Adopted @sch's way of removing items.  It's his answer that should be accepted. I just kept this one for the while-loop.